# OpenCL - how to make helper function return array and transfer portion of memory from constant memory space to private

Tags: c++, opencl

Lets say I have the following functions:

```
float* get_value(__constant float * A){
  float temp[2];
  temp[0] = A[0];
  temp[1] = A[1];
  printf("A[0]: %.2f, temp[0]: %.2f",A[0],temp[0]);
  return temp;
}

__kernel
void matmul(__constant float * A){
   float * vec1 = get_value(A);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

In this method, as the code itself explains, I have tried to return an array from a helper function to kernel, which calls it. The line where I assign `temp[0] = A[0];` is apparently not working for some reason. However openclc does throw a warning though

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable
  'array' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
```

Could someone please explain what is wrong in returning an address of an array associated with local memory space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (this is not strictly an OpenCL problem, it is due to the fact that temporary variables inside a function will "disappear" when you leave the function, so returning a pointer to your local variables now points at "something that shouldn't be used", and the compiler correctly identifies this)

Use the construct of passing an array into `get_value`, something like:

```
    float vec1[2];
    get_value(A, vec1);
```

and make `get_value` something like this:

```
float* get_value(__constant float * A, private float *res){
   res[0] = A[0];
   res[1] = A[1];
}
```

Comment: Apparently the method you suggested isn't working though. Please look at my code https://github.com/rajkumarcm/OpenCL/blob/master/Kernels/matmul.cl#L94

Comment: Without knowing what error you get (or "what doesn't work"), I'm not sure what to suggest, but I have suspicion that variable length arrays are quite restricted in OpenCL.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors or warnings anymore, but when I print the assigned value, it doesn't contain the value I am expecting.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why that would be, can't see anything obviously wrong in your code. Try with a simpler example first, and see if that works.